# The has_one :through Association! How Create connect between AccountHistory and Supplier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account
  has_one :account_history, through: :account
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_one :account_history
end

class AccountHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
end
```

For some reason, in rails 6 can't create connect between `Supplier` and `AccountHistory`!

Need example how can create this connection if we have exist `Supplier` and exist `AccountHistory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, I already found a solution!

```
Account.first.build_supplier(supplier_id: 1).save
```